# PHP Warning: Module 'json' already loaded

Tags: php

While executing my PHP code in editor (Eclipse), I am getting this error:

> PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0.

What's the problem here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: is it running on browser or not? eclipse is not server.. and please paste some code

Comment: It's probably using Apache. Are you attempting to load the module twice in your php.ini?

Comment: How to notice whether module loaded twice or not

Comment: look in the php.ini for something like 'extension = json.so'. It could also be done via a `php_value` override in httpd.conf/.htaccess. Find that, remove/comment it, and see if the warning disappears but JSON still works.

Comment: Hi @Marc, I have checked both in php.ini and httpd.conf file for extension = json.so and php_value. both are not there.

Answer (score 3):

What version of PHP are you running? Have you recently upgraded from an older version?

The JSON module only became a standard part of PHP in v5.2; prior to that you would have had to added the PECL JSON module into it yourself.

If you've upgraded to 5.2 or 5.3, but you've still got an old config which is trying to add the PECL JSON module, then it will conflict with the JSON module that is now built into PHP.

Try to find where you're including the PECL module and remove it. Your JSON functions should continue to work as before.

Comment: I haven't upgraded the php. And I have installed XAMPP 1.7.0

Comment: Ho to identify the find where I have included the PECL module?

Answer (score 2):

Search the line **extension=json.so** in the **php.ini** and Remove or change to **;extension=json.so**

Comment: Counter-productive if you have to have `extension=json` in there due to a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to check at folder `php.d` (in my case at centos) than check file `20-json.ini`